# Angular ngrx can not pass component to action, not immutable

Tags: angular, ngrx

i am trying to implement my dialog state management which looks like this :

Component :

```
  public openLoginDialog(){
    this.store.dispatch(
      DialogActions.openDialog({
      payload: {
        component: LoginDialogComponent,
         config: {
          styleClass: 'auth-custom-dialog',
          modal: true,
          showHeader: false,
          closeOnEscape: true,
          dismissableMask: true,
         },
      } as InitDialogPayload
    }))
  }
```

Actions :

```
export const DialogActions = {
    openDialog: createAction('[Dialog] Open Dialog', props<{ payload: InitDialogPayload }>(),),
    updateDialog : createAction('[Dialog] Update Dialog', props<{ payload: UpdateDialogPayload }>()),
    closeDialog : createAction('[Dialog] Close Dialog', props<{ payload: CloseDialogPayload }>()),
    confirmDialog : createAction('[Dialog] Close Dialog', props<{ payload: ConfirmDialogPayload }>())
}
```

Reducers and Effects :

```
  export const dialogReducer = createReducer(
    initialDialogState,
    on(DialogActions.openDialog, (state, { payload }) => {
      const dialogId = uuidv4();
      const newDialog: IDialogState = {
        config: payload.config,
        dialogId,
        dialogRef: undefined,
      };
      return {
        ...state,
        dialogs: [...state.dialogs, newDialog],
      };
    }),
    ...

export class DialogEffects {
  openDialog$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DialogActions.openDialog),
    tap(action => {
      this.customDialogService.openDialog(action.payload as InitDialogPayload);
    }),
  ), {dispatch: false});

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private customDialogService: CustomDialogsService) {}
}
```

And my customDialogService which calls another service to open the dialog :

```
  public openDialog(content: InitDialogPayload){
      const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(content.component, content.config);
      dialogRef.onClose.subscribe((result: any) => {
        DialogActions.closeDialog({payload: {
          dialogId:content.dialogId
        } as CloseDialogPayload})
      });
  }
```

The problem :

When i pass component through ngrx state action and reducer it does not work, because it becomes not extensible :

> Cannot add property **NG_ELEMENT_ID**, object is not extensible

**I found temporary fix, i set strictActionImmutability to false and it works :**

provideStore(reducers, {
runtimeChecks: {
strictActionImmutability: false
}
}),

**But this works globally, how can I fix it or I should use different approach for this ?**

Comment: That's a very strange approach. Why would you want to pass the component via NgRx, it breaks Immutable State paradigm. It also looks like you are reusing an Action, which is one of a points in Good Action Hygiene - don't do that. Why can't you just call the Dialog Service directly?

Comment: I totally support @mat.hudak. The fact that you can do something doesn't mean you should do it ;) Also you have to remember that NGRX provides **global state management** functionality. In your case you don't change the global state (at least I don't see where it would be required in your case), so IMHO you shouldn't use NGRX in this part of your code.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it cleared my mind about the global state management

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't pass the component to action, you pass a component type. Those a different things.
2. @mat.hudak already wrote about the weird way of opening a modal dialog. I totally support his opinion.

Regarding your problem: it doesn't have a nice solution. Here is explained why: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44610